# JavaFX - Objects stuck in the memory

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a huge application built using `JavaFX`,, as there are a lot of stages to show i created a class to load views [more like utils class] called `FXMLManager`(i think the problem is there),, To show a single stage i should create an instance of `FXMLManager`,, after the stage is closed `FXMLManager` instances remains in the memory,,, i tried setting the object to null after the stage is closed with no luck..

`FXMLManager.java`:

```
public class FXMLManager<T extends AbstractController> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static ClassLoader cachingClassLoader = new FXMLlightweightLoader(FXMLLoader.getDefaultClassLoader());

    private final Class<T> clazzType;
    @Getter private T controller;
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
    @Getter private Parent root;

    public FXMLManager(Class<T> clazz) {

        this.clazzType = clazz;

        Annotation annotation = this.clazzType.getAnnotation(FXMLController.class);

        if (annotation == null)
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    "controller type provided is not annotated with FXMLController : " + clazzType);

        FXMLController fxmlController = (FXMLController) annotation;

        this.fxmlLoader = constructFXMLLoader();
        this.fxmlLoader.setLocation(getURL(fxmlController.value()));

        try {
            AbstractController abstractController = (AbstractController) clazzType.newInstance();
            this.fxmlLoader.setController(abstractController);

            this.root = (Parent) this.fxmlLoader.load();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.controller = this.fxmlLoader.getController();

    }

    private FXMLLoader constructFXMLLoader() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setClassLoader(cachingClassLoader);
        fxmlLoader.setResources(I18NSupport.getBundle());
        return fxmlLoader;
    }


    public T getController(Class<T> controllerType) {
        T controller = controllerType.cast(this.fxmlLoader.getController());
        return controller;
    }


    public static URL getURL(String url) {
        return FXMLManager.class.getResource(url);
    }

    private Stage stage;

    public Stage getStage(String title) {

        if (stage == null) {
            Scene scene = new Scene(this.root);
            stage = new Stage();

            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setScene(scene);

            stage.getIcons().add(ImageLoader.loadImage("icon"));
        }

        stage.setTitle(title);
        return stage;
    }

}
```

i am using `FXMLManager` as follows:

```
public static void openRandomForm() {

    FXMLManager<Controller> fxmlManager = new FXMLManager<>(Controller.class);
    //fxmlManager.getController();  do stuff with the controller
    Stage stage = fxmlManager.getStage("title");
    stage.showAndWait();
    fxmlManager = null;
}
```

Am i doing something wrong? as far as i know `FXMLManager` should be cleared,, no?
Screen shots of heap dump after showing couple of stages then performing `GC`:
[image]
[image]

Comment: *Note* There is no guarantee that GC will clean up an object at a given time, so consider that first! Outside of that, the only explanation for it not being cleaned up is that something is maintaining a reference (Excluding thread related GC issues). Stage seems most likely... specifically this line  Scene scene = new Scene(this.root);  in your Stage instance, you could check to see if you can get from Stage.Scene.Parent (Idk the names of your properties, so I used types there) to this class. If you can, your Stage is maintaining a reference indirectly to this class.

Comment: @MarkW thank you very much,, thats really helpful. one question thou,,would it be better if i just show the stage inside the same class? i mean the stage will not be accessible from outside that class,, or that would not make difference

Comment: I'm not going to be much help with respect to javafx design practices. It's just not something I'm super familiar with. I'm sure there are resources you could go through to find those best practices though.... Maybe start here? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/best_practices/jfxpub-best_practices.htm